# ArcGIS Desktop, Attribute Table with drop down menus

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, domains

Essentially, I have a dataset with drop down menus in one column, but I can't edit it or add new text.

I have managed to delete the original text classification in the field, but can't add 'Camel Race Track' to the DropDownMenu.

[image: DropDownMenu_Issue]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your database has Domain or dataset has subtype. If you want to manage them you can add more parameters for the domain or subtype.
see Create [subtypes and attribute domains](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/exercise-3-creating-subtypes-and-attribute-domains.htm) 
to manage domains :

- Right click to the database , select properties then click Domains
  tab. now you can edit or delete domains.

to manage subtypes:

- right click to the feature class , select properties then click
  subtype tab.

Comment: dang I was just about to post that too! ya beat me to it! Anyway this is exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Appologies, I never said thank you. Looks like a good solution. Many thanks.